# Removing Irregular Transient Spike from Linear data trend

Tags: fitting, data, filtering

The x-y data that is being analyzed generates a linear relationship (y=mx+b) when in steady-state flow.  NON-REGULAR transients are often introduced into the system.  These transients prevent the fitting of a linear relationship to the raw data.  I am looking for advice on how to improve the identification of these transients automatically.  Using `FindAnomalies` appears to select the steady state data more often the transient data (see plot down further below) - particulary in the case of the `Multinormal` method.

Ideally, the following criteria must be met:

- The analyst does not want to manually remove the transient data
- If we can identify (therefore remove) the transient points, we can easily generate our own linear regression (or other procedure) for generating the  linear relationship
- The steady state condition is always a linear relationship with a negative slope
- The analyst can adjust the tolerance, nothing more

As indicated, I am using the `FindAnomalies` function experimenting with the `Method` detect the transient spikes and then remove them using `AnomalyPositions` property.

A review of the plot below will shows the points which are being detected by `FindAnomalies` using both `Multinormal` and `KernelDensityEstimation` methods.  Even with small tolerances, the function tends to identify on trend data as an anomaly.

[image: Visualization of detected anomalies]

The complete code for the demonstration is below.  Any advice or suggestions is appreciated

```
Manipulate[
 TR = FindAnomalies[data[[All, 2]], AcceptanceThreshold -> ACT, 
   Method -> "Multinormal"];
 TR2 = FindAnomalies[data[[All, 2]], "AnomalyPositions", 
    AcceptanceThreshold -> ACT, Method -> "Multinormal"] // Flatten;
 
 XR = FindAnomalies[data[[All, 2]], AcceptanceThreshold -> ACT, 
   Method -> "KernelDensityEstimation"];
 XR2 = FindAnomalies[data[[All, 2]], "AnomalyPositions", 
    AcceptanceThreshold -> ACT, Method -> "KernelDensityEstimation"] //
    Flatten;
 
 AnomData = Table[
        {
                data[[TR2[[t]], 1]], TR[[t]]
    
            }, {t, 1, Length[TR]}
        ];
 
 XAnomData = Table[
        {
                data[[XR2[[t]], 1]], XR[[t]]
    
            }, {t, 1, Min[Length[XR], Length[XR2]]}
        ];
 ListPlot[{AnomData, XAnomData, data},
            PlotMarkers -> {{"\[Alpha]", 11}, {"\[Beta]", 10}, {"\[Gamma]", 
     3}},
            Joined -> {False, False, True},
            GridLines -> Automatic,
            PlotLegends -> {"Multinormal", "KernelDensityEstimation", 
    "Raw Data"}
        ],
 {{ACT, 0.2, "Tolerance"}, 0.01, 1, 0.01}
 
 ]
```

Comment: Related:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224980/how-to-drop-points-that-dont-lie-in-a-line/224982#224982.

Comment: Thanks @JimB, I will take a look