# Nonlinear Model Fitting to Numerical Data with automatic elimination

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, replacement, nonlinear, autocomplete

I have an experimental data set {f,x,y,z}  as

> {{300., 2., 4., 6.}, {500., 0., 4., 25.}, {6600., 1., 15., 9.}, {100.,
> 5., 0., 2.}, {1100., 10., 8., 1.}, {1300., 7., 8., 18.}, {300.,
> 23., 5., 0.}, {400., 1., 5., 3.}, {900., 3., 7., 9.}, {800., 4., 7.,
> 2.}, {400., 4., 4., 11.}, {3300., 24., 12., 0.}, {600., 2., 6.,
> 8.}, {300., 2., 4., 6.}, {600., 22., 6., 7.}, {17900., 3., 21.,
> 44.}}

I need to find the best fitted parameters for the function:

> f=a*`(x*b)`^0.3 + c*`(y*d)`^3 + e*`(z*h)`^g

where a, b, c, d, e, h, g is the fitted parameters.
The problem is how to drop a certain data line with a higher deviation than a certain value e.g greater than 10% and then restart the finding parameters to have the best fitted parameters.
The another problem is how to guess the initials (starting points) for the parameters.
Could you please advise how to solve the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: `a*(x*b)^0.3` is the same as `(a b^0.3)x^0.3 `, so you can replace that term by a single parameter `A x^0.3 `. Similarly the other terms are overparametrized.

Comment: Have a look at the [RANSAC algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus).

Comment: Just to echo @Coolwater 's comments:  The practical answer is that you can't estimate all of those parameters.  The slightly longer answer is that there are an infinite number of estimates of those parameters (i.e., there is no unique set of values that minimize the sum of squares or maximize the likelihood).  You can estimate $a_1=a b^{0.3}$ but not $a$ and $b$ individually.

Comment: Both `NonlinearModelFit` and `LinearModelFit` require that the response variable (`f`) be in the last position (and not the first as your question indicates).

Comment: Possible duplicate?  The 2 answers here (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224980/how-to-drop-points-that-dont-lie-in-a-line/224982#224982) are great if I say so myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of automatically tossing data (although the RANSAC algorithm mentioned by @Roman is great for finding potential outliers - just as long as one doesn't toss data without thinking especially if you have only 16 data points and are fitting 5 parameters: $a$, $c$, $e$, $g$, and the error variance).

But in this case your model doesn't seem to produce any outliers and ends up with a near perfect fit.

To get `NonlinearModelFit` to get you parameter estimates (but no estimates of associated standard errors) one needs to use `Method = "NMinimize"`:

```
data = {{300, 2, 4, 6}, {500, 0, 4, 25}, {6600, 1, 15, 9}, {100, 5, 0, 2}, {1100, 10, 8, 1}, 
  {1300, 7, 8, 18}, {300, 23, 5, 0}, {400, 1, 5, 3}, {900, 3, 7, 9}, {800, 4, 7, 2}, 
  {400, 4, 4, 11}, {3300, 24, 12, 0}, {600, 2, 6, 8}, {300, 2, 4, 6}, {600, 22, 6, 7}, 
  {17900, 3, 21, 44}};
(* Rearrange data to form needed by NonlinearModelFit *)
data[[All, {2, 3, 4, 1}]] = data;

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {a x^(3/10) + c y^3 + e z^g, a > 0 && c > 0 && e > 0 && g > 0}, 
  {a, c, e, g}, {x, y, z}, Method -> "NMinimize", MaxIterations -> 5000];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 18.0549, c -> 1.88037, e -> 71.9428, g -> 0.496803} *)
```

I think that `Method -> "NMinimize"` is needed because without that the part of the model with `e z^g` chokes on the values of `z` that are zero.  This also probably causes the inability to produce standard errors of the parameters.  (Maybe there's a simple way to get around that.)

A plot of the predicted value vs. the observed value doesn't show (to me) any abnormalities:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{nlm["PredictedResponse"], data[[All, 4]]}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"Predicted response", "Observed response"},
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Predicted vs observed response]

The adjusted $R^2$ value is

```
nlm["AdjustedRSquared"]
(* 0.999971 *)
```

A plot of the residuals vs the predicted value also shows no abnormalities:

```
ListPlot[Transpose[{nlm["PredictedResponse"], nlm["FitResiduals"]}], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"Predicted response", "Residual"},
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Predicted vs residual]

If what you presented was just an example dataset and still want to know how to use something like the RANSAC algorithm, then having a dataset with at least one obvious outlier would be better.

If, however, this is the dataset of interest and standard errors are needed for the parameters, then that can be added.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I have hundred of thousand experimental data points and many of them are abnormal during the experiment thus I want to drop the abnormal data which are not fit to the found function. Could you please advise with the code?